# Is it possible to calculate consecutive digits of $\pi^{1/\pi}$

Tags: infinity, pi, upper-lower-bounds

This question is inspired by a [challenge on codegolf.stackexchange.com](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/185842/31516), where the task is to:

> Output consecutive digits of $x = \pi^{1/\pi}$ forever.

That is, calculate digits of $x$, and output one by one forever (in theory). As this should go on forever, you must continuously calculate new digits of $\pi$ and $x$. There are known ways to calculate individual digits of $\pi$, but as far as I can tell, digit $n$ of $\pi^{1/\pi}$ may rely on digit $n+m$ of $\pi$.

At some point, you'll encounter something like $...31999999999999999...$ if you calculate $x$ with a given accuracy for $pi$. However, if you had a higher accuracy, this might result in $...3200000000000...$ instead.

I'm fairly certain that it can be proven/shown that digit $n$ may rely on digit $n+m$ of $\pi$ for some $n$ and $m$ (but *I* can't). What I'm not sure of is, can an upper bound of $m$ be proven? Is it possible to say, with absolute certainty, that the $n$<sup>th</sup> digit of $x$ is correct if we have calculated for instance $n+10$ digits of $\pi$?

Comment: This is the table maker's dilemma. Note that in order to have an algorithm you don't need to have an upper bound on $m=m_n$. You only need to know that $m_n$ is finite. Either a proof that the number is irrational, or its exact value if it is irrational would sufice. An algorithm that computes larger and larger sections of the number terminates deciding the value of digit $n$, if you know that the number is irrational. The problem here is that, as far as I know, we don't know if $\pi^{1/\pi}$ is irrational or rational.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do come across $\ldots3199999999\ldots$, then you just have to keep going until the issue resolves itself as either $x\le\ldots3199999999$ or $x\ge\ldots32$. If $x$ is known to be irrational, then you can be sure that this procedure will eventually terminate.

It can be difficult to predict in advance how much look-ahead you will need. In practice, however, unless $x$ has been specially chosen to be awkward, you will only need to calculate a few more decimal places.

But if $x$ is not known to be irrational, then you have a genuine problem on your hands. I am pretty sure that $\pi^{1/\pi}$ is irrational, but I wouldn't know how to prove it.

Comment: This [StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49649503/2586922) explains how to compute the amount of look-ahead on the fly

Comment: @LuisMendo: I wouldn't say that it _explains_ how to do it. It's more of a guide to the various options available in off-the-shelf software, none of which solves the problem as stated. In particular, there is nothing in that link about how to predict the amount of look-ahead that you will need before you have actually looked ahead...

Comment: That's my point, you can't predict it. It has to be done on the fly: look ahead until you know you have looked enough, depending on the specific digits you see. The described approach is appliable for any programming language that has variable-precision arithmetic, even if that answer uses Matlab/Octave. This is a great answer BTW, not sure why it was downvoted